# Why javascript function name custom is a lower case word followed by a capitalized word, just like `orangeCost`?

Tags: javascript

I was learning javascript from codecademy today.

There is one thing that confuse me a lot, in its tutorial, it use function names like `orangeCost`. like in this link:
http://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-beginner-en-6LzGd/1/1?curriculum_id=506324b3a7dffd00020bf661

In my behaviour, I feel both  `orange_cost` and `OrangeCost` just fine.

Why in this broadly read tutorial, they use such variable name(`orangeCost`)?

Is there some history in it, or it can prevent some kind of catastrophe?

Comment: It has nothing to do with preventing catastrophes and everything to do with what format you prefer. Both of your examples are valid and work fine. Voting to close as opinion based.

Comment: It's just convention. Functions whose first letter is a capital are conventionally constructor functions, and others are not. The language itself doesn't care.

Comment: Please see this question on [naming conventions](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/27264/naming-conventions-camelcase-versus-underscore-case-what-are-your-thoughts-ab)

Answer (score 1):

It's just a human convention.

In other environments, instead of using *camel-casing*, they use *pascal-casing* (*orangeJuice* would be camel-casing while *OrangeJuice* pascal-casing).

Conventions are powerful to let others understand our code as it's written in a standarized way.

It could happen that some convention would be *ugly*, but it's better to follow a convention than going alone the way.

Anyway, either camel or pascal casing aren't ugly per se. It's just our taste what turns something into ugly or beautiful.

### An exception to the rule

[Brainfuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) code is *ugly*. I believe that there's a human convention about this ;)

Comment: So `orange_cost` is also allowed in javascript? Which has no difference with `orangeCost`?

Comment: @Zen No difference. You can use whatever convention you want to use. The issue here is no one uses the underscore convention so far

Comment: So what trouble I may cause to other programmers if I use underscore convention in javascript? As I was used to do so in python.

Comment: @Zen They will find your code ugly. Simply. You need to adapt yourself to each programming language. I do this everyday, as I use both C# and JavaScript and their naming conventions aren't completely different, but they've differences at all.

Comment: @Zen Will your fingers explode if you use camel-cased function names? :D

Comment: @ Matías Fidemraizer, No, it won't, probably. So the javascript basically use Camel-case, but the pascal-casing is preserved for constructor functions. So normal function went for lowerCamelCase. Is it?

Comment: @Zen Yeah!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!